# REST Standards - Should output models always match input models?

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api

So I have the requirement that part of the output models must include UI important information. This information is essentially text translations and suggested formats for dates, prices, lengths.

So an example of an output model could be:

```
{
  statuses : {
    enumValue1 : "Display This Text",
    enumValue2 : "Display This Text2",
  },
  thePrice : {
    value : 3.50,
    formattedValue : "$3.50"
  },
  length : {
    meters 3,
    formattedValue : "3 ft."
  },
  iAmAPropertyOnlyInGet : 42
}
```

Now if I have this as my output model, is it "ok" to have a completely different input model?

```
{
  status : {
    enumValue1,
    enumValue2,
  },
  thePrice : 3.50,
  lengthInMeters : 3  
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your service needs to actually be REST? A service that returns JSON is not necessarily REST.

Comment: "Needs" is an odd term to use. I would say that the project has a strong desire to build a standard, easy to use, and understandable API. The decision was to build a REST API in order keep things standard.

Comment: REST is not a standard. If you treat it like one, you'll find that your service adheres to no standard at all. REST is an architecture, and your project may not require all of that architecture. For instance, is it required that everything in your service be a "resource"? Is it necessary that all relationships between one resource and another be specified via URLs?

Comment: I don't know how to answer your question properly. People make those kinds of decisions, so if a person says yes to that, then it's a yes, otherwise it's not. So the service itself cannot have that requirement, but the person making the decisions. So if I just arbitrarily said yes, that's just me self-fulfilling a requirement on REST. It is an API exposed over HTTP that utilizes the HTTP protocol for accessing resources. All decisions made by people. We did so because it creates an understanding of how the service will function.

Comment: I might need to clarify when I ask if the models should match, I am asking "If you are given what you are told is a REST API, should they match? Does it matter to you?"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Representations you send to the origin server can be completely different than the representations you receive. Consider the way web browsers work.  You GET `text/html` and you POST `application/x-www-urlencoded-form`.

When using the PUT method it is normal for what you PUT and what GET to be similar if not identical.

The REST architectural style puts no constraints on the shape of the HTTP payloads, other than the fact that the semantics must be explicitly specified in the message.

So, in fact, sharing a model type between a client and server without explicitly identifying that type in the message is a violation of the self-descriptive REST sub-constraint.

Comment: +1 "can be completely different than the representations you receive"

Comment: And how would a person be expected to update a resource from an API?

Comment: @BradLaney Not sure I follow your question.  You must be explicit about what you send, but the server is then free to interpret how it likes.

Comment: I'm saying what is the work flow for a person updating a resource. First they get the resource. Then they create a new type to put, then they copy all the content from the get object, to their put object, then update the fields they want to change. Then they submit the put object hoping they didn't make a mistake and update things they didn't want.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what kind of flexibility you want to give your clients (REST service consumers).

If you maintain the same model, then the consumer can load an existing model, modify values, and then send it back, which is very natural with CRUD scenarios.

However, if you expect to have two separate scenarios: 1- to import data and 2- to export data, then may be they could be different.

In general, think about it as a model in your application (your problem domain). Define server-side model structure (this is obviously **only one**), and then think about ways to expose it. To me, when looking at these two models outlined in the question, they seem similar. I would even recommend to support any input format (either of these) and one output format (at a time, may depend on the request headers).

Comment: What about properties that are not allowed as input? I modified the model to be more accurate to this issue.

Comment: As I understand you are talking about redundant data. These may be ignored probably, since usually there is always a lot of garbage which you don't care of. On the other hand, expected input should be validated (model validation using annotation attributes in MVC).

Comment: +1 for "If you maintain the same model, then the consumer can load an existing model, modify values, and then send it back, which is very natural with CRUD scenarios."

Answer (score 0):

I would have kept meta information in separate object besides data itself.

So in JSON response, first object would be like

```
{ meta:  { priceformat: $, lengthformat: ft },
 thePrice: 3.50,
 length: X
}
```

Comment: How does this address text values for the enums?

Comment: I am not sure I have got your concern but enums text values can be handled as separate object just like meta

Comment: So a list of all available formats as meta? meta: { statuses: { foo : "bar", foo2 : "bar2" } }, model : { statuses : [foo] } ?

Comment: An issue I see with this solution, is that the user has to know when to apply the lengthformat meta data. We have weight, length, and distance. And if they use our collection of items, they loop over them and show them to the user. How would they know which ones which, in the collection? They would have to go based on name?